# Get action and controller name from Url, Yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Im new to Yii, and not sure is it possible to get action and controller names from url like:

```
/my_proj/backend/web/index.php?r=user%2Fcreate
```

I need to get them in controller(`php`) or client side (`jQuery`).

I need it because, on button click:

```
 <?= Html::button(Yii::t('app', Yii::t('app','Create')), ['value' => Url::to(['create']),'class' => 'btn btn-success modalButton', 'id' => 'create-user']) ?>
```

I want to check if the current user has permissions for `create` action. I need this on client side, because I show create view in modal dialog, and if user does not have permission, i don't need to show popup.

```
  $(".modalButton").click(function(){  
   var permission = ?? //$(this)[0].id; //id works ok, but looking for another way

    $.get('index.php?r=site/check-permission', {'permission': permission}, function(isAllowed){ 
        if(isAllowed == 1)
        {
            $(".modal").modal("show")
                       .find(".modalContent")
                       .load($(".modalButton").attr('value'));
        }
   }); 

  return false;   
});
```

I tried to use `id` for button, and specify permission there, but looking for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you need 
In view file -

```
$this->uniqueid - controller name
$this->action->Id - action name. 

// ($this is CController instance)
```

This is for the current controller

```
<?php echo $this->getUniqueId();?>
```

**OR**

```
Yii::app()->controller->id
```

**OR**

```
Yii::app()->getController()->getId()
```

[see this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#getController-detail)

**OR**

Yes you can get the current controller/action route, by reversing urlManager rule:

```
Yii::app()->urlManager->parseUrl(Yii::app()->request)
```

Comment: this gets action name of the current controller, but I have this `create` button in `index` view of `user` model, and I'm checking permission in another controller `site`

Comment: could you use the urlManager ?

Comment: $queryParams  i think this will give some result [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html#$queryParams-detail)

Comment: @GyuzalR  could this help `Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(array_merge([Yii::$app->requestedRoute], $getParams));`